# How do ETFs process dividends?

Tags: taxes, investing, etf, fees, dividend-reinvestment

Presumably at least some of the stock shares held by an Exchange Traded mutual Fund produce dividends.

Do those dividends just get pocketed by (and taxed upon) the fund managers, as their income to pay for ongoing operating costs of the fund?

(Background: It is claimed that ETFs are more tax efficient because they don't return taxable dividends; the reinvestment is invisible and it's all capital gains. But *someone* is being taxed on those dividends, and *someone* is paying the fund managers, so the best guess I've got is that those costs are usually covered by taking money from the dividend stream before it gets reinvested. Which would mean the tax inefficiency is still there, just buried in the fund's operations and reflected as a lower valuation of the fund than the pile of shares it holds is nominally worth. Unless that in turn is buried by shareholders overvaluing the fund shares...)

Comment: Semantics, but ETF stands for Exchange Traded Fund, since they are like a mutual fund but are traded on the exchange like stocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe stock dividends are "passed through" to the investors of the ETF. The managers don't actually take any. This means the dividend taxes are paid by the ETF shareholders. Dividend Reinvestment Plans (DRIP) do not currently exist for ETFs like they do for company stocks.

Also, the tax efficiency for ETFs is due to the lack of capital gains they pay out (unlike mutual funds). This is because they can transfer company shares in-kind with "Authorized Participants" which eliminates the taxable event.

[Here](https://www.jhinvestments.com/viewpoints/investing-basics/what-makes-etfs-tax-efficient) is a good article:

> ETF manager works with authorized participants (or APs) to bundle (purchase for share creation) or disassemble (sell for share redemption) an underlying basket of the fund’s securities. The process of bundling securities and delivering them into the ETF in the form of a creation unit occurs in kind and allows the fund to inject ETF shares of equivalent value into the market, satisfying rising investor demand.
>
> ...
>
> Neither mechanism of creation or redemption is taxable to the ETF
> itself ...

Comment: I'll take your word for. It. Sounds like a loophole, but loopholes do exist... And doesn't address the (possibly separate) question of how investment houses profit, or even break even, from running ETFs. TANSTAAFL...

Comment: @keshlam ETFs still have fees, even if small (VOO is 0.03%), unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: Ah. My misunderstanding, then.

Comment: I guess your are talking about taxes in the US

Comment: Expenses in an ETF, including any manager's fee, ARE paid out of investment income, and the same for a traditional fund. For either of them in US, net investment income MUST be distributed to shareholders by year-end -- some funds do so quarterly or monthly and some wait until Dec -- and is included in taxable income whether or not the shareholder reinvests it (some other countries have 'accumulating' funds where net income remains in the fund). You're right that US trad funds must _also_ distribute net realized cap gains, which ETFs avoid.

Comment: I don't know if ETFs can be DRiPped in general, but brokers can offer that service. I have a few ETFs at a couple of different brokers where I have dividends automatically reinvested (automatic to me, I assume the broker is just buying sufficient shares to cover all the reinvestments for all their customers then apportioning out shares).